# What does where returns on rails ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails console to inspect ActiveRecord functionality on Rails.
    class Test < ActiveRecord:Base

```
@temp = Test.where(:user_id => 1)
```

So @temp here is an ActiveRecord but when I am trying to access a field

```
@temp.user_id
```

I am getting an error, I have to do that

```
@temp[0].user_id
```

to get the value, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass.where
```

returns an array of activerecord results. You want to use

```
Test.find_by_user_id(1)
```

This will return a single record. If you have multiple records with the same user_id it will return the first.